# How to create a hashmap with borrowed keys?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a lookup table of a list of items, but the naive approach violates the borrow checker.

```
    struct Item {
       key: String,
       value: i64
    }

    let item1 = Item {
       key: "a".into(),
       value: 1
    };
    
    let item2 = Item {
       key: "b".into(),
       value: 2
    };
    
    
    let list: HashMap<&String, Item> = HashMap::from_iter([
       (&item1.key, item1),
       (&item2.key, item2),
    ]);
```

I'm aware that you can use `Rc`, but that seems like massive overkill when you (the programmer) knows the that the lifetime of the keys will match the lifetime of the values.

I know that the compiler itself can't verify this, are there any data-structures/annotations that can indicate the lifetimes of the key matching it's respective value?

Comment: You say that you know that the lifetimes will match, but at the same time you're literally moving all `Item`s, which means they don't actually exist anymore

Comment: I'm not dropping item1 or item2.

Comment: `item1` and `item2` is moved into the `HashMap`. They no longer exist as `item1` and `item2` after `from_iter()`. So you're not able to reference their `.key` as the keys

Comment: Right, but you're missing the point of the question.  I'm posting code that doesn't work to demonstrate something you can't do, while trying to make it clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You cannot at the same time have an item and the reference to that item in the hashmap. Instead, you could put your items in a different structure (say a `Vec`) and use references to both the key and the item in the hashmap.

Comment: > You cannotat the same time have an item and the reference to that item in the hashmap

I know this, the code is demonstrative, not literally meant to work.

Comment: If you don't want to clone your keys (nor `Item`s), then you can't have `HashMap<&String, Item>` like that. Unless you e.g. change `key` into `&String` or `&'static str`, such that the `key` is stored elsewhere. Otherwise you can do `HashMap<&String, &Item>` or, well, `HashMap<String, Item>`

Comment: I think the point is that, in this case, Rust doesn't refuse your code because it wrongly thinks it is incorrect, it does so because it correctly thinks it is incorrect, so no matter the language you are trying to use, this won't work. If you simply removed any lifetime checking of Rust and forced the compiler to generate code, you would have bugged software. This is because `item1` is moved (that is, it is copied into a new location and the old data becomes undefined), so the pointer to the key actually points to undefined data.